# java: Check string with special characters except few

Tags: java, string

I am reading sensor's memory and I want to make sure the returned string is a valid string, as it sometimes return garbage values from the memory.
I want to skip those garbage values.
I know I can check string with special characters using Patterns

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher mat = pat.matcher("My Test String");
if(mat.find())
{
    System.out.println("String contains special character!");
}
```

but a string with these special characters [,./?@:;#!"£$%^&*()_+=-~><|`] should be valid string but not garbage (like )

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could strip "invalid" characters like this.

```
text = text.replaceAll("[^\u0020-\u007e]+", "");
```

Comment: That's perfect.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy, just add these special characters in the pattern and it should be fine.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 {},./?@:;#!£$%^&*()_+=-~><|`]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher("My Test String");
        if(mat.find())
        {
            System.out.println("String contains special character!");
        }
```

It will not accept any other character except these.

Comment: I doubt this would work as you'll need to escape `*` and `+` (and possibly other special characters)

Comment: It works for me.. Only double quote `"` doesn't work... but yes the other answer is more accurate for the asker which has been accepted anyway.